# On mobile, how do I stack my bootstrap nav tabs vertically?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have five bootstrap nav tabs that are evenly spaced and look great on desktop. On mobile the text of the tabs get squished together. On mobile, how do I have the tabs stack vertically?

[image]

It's in the middle of the page so I'd like the five tabs to stack on mobile.

Here's my bootply:
http://www.bootply.com/nM8Q1MftKU

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="content-section-c">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <h2>Sample Search Results</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="tabbable">
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
          <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">ELECTRONIC<br>APPLE TREES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">CROSSING GUARD<br>ORANGE TREES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">POLICE BODY<br>PEARS TREES</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">PARKING METERS<br>&nbsp;</a></li>
          <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">TRANSPORTATION<br>GRAPES TREES</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
          <div id="pane1" class="tab-pane active">
            <p class="results">126 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="pane2" class="tab-pane">
            <p class="results">75 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/05_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/06_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/07_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/08_card.png"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="pane3" class="tab-pane">
            <p class="results">144 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/09_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/10_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/11_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/12_card.png"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="pane4" class="tab-pane">
            <p class="results">170 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div>
          </div>
          <div id="pane5" class="tab-pane">
            <p class="results">256 Results Founds</p>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/01_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/02_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/03_card.png"></div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
              <img class="img-responsive" src="http://www.onvia.com/responsive/04_card.png"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.tab-content -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.tabbable -->
    </div>

  </div>
  <!-- /.container -->
</div>
<!-- /.content-section-c -->
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.content-section-c {
  padding: 50px 0;
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: #3C5A78;
  line-height: 1;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0 0 16px 0;
}
.nav-tabs>li.active>a,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:focus,
.nav-tabs>li.active>a:hover {
  border-top: none;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #e9a39c;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #d4d4d4 !important;
}
.nav-tabs>li>a:hover {
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.nav>li>a:focus,
.nav>li>a:hover {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
}
.nav-tabs {
  border-bottom: none;
  display: inline-block;
  /* needed to center the list items */
}
.tabbable {
  text-align: center;
}
.results {
  font-family: 'Merriweather', serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #355A78;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 20px 0 5px 0;
  text-align: left;
}
.nav-tabs {
  width: 100%
}
.nav-tabs > li {
  width: 20%;
}
```

Comment: Try to use small fonts in smaller size??

Comment: Or you can use word-break:break all in smaller screen.

Answer (score 3):

Change the width of the nav-tabs > li in mobile sizes

```
@media screen and (max-width:767px){
  .nav-tabs > li {width:100%;}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could consider a collapsing navbar. See your example on [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Ng1JhTfPN5). On small screens there will be the three vertical lines to open the navbar navigation instead of showing all possible links on one vertical line.

Desktop:[image: navbar]
Mobile: [image: navbar closed][image: navbar open]

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li class="active"><a href="#pane1" data-toggle="tab">ELECTRONIC<br>APPLE TREES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane2" data-toggle="tab">CROSSING GUARD<br>ORANGE TREES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane3" data-toggle="tab">POLICE BODY<br>PEARS TREES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">PARKING METERS<br>&nbsp;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#pane4" data-toggle="tab">TRANSPORTATION<br>GRAPES TREES</a></li> 
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```